# PHP Array. Убрать дубли и перезаписать значение [option] из дублей

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Всем привет! Есть массив, который приходит на view:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => product_1
        [model] => model_1
        [option] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 47
                        [name] => Размер
                        [value] => 39
                    )
            )
        [quantity] => 10
    )
  [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => product_1
        [model] => model_1
        [option] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 47
                        [name] => Размер
                        [value] => 40
                    )
            )
        [quantity] => 20
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [name] => product_2
        [model] => model_2
        [option] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 55
                        [name] => Размер
                        [value] => 44
                    )
            )
        [quantity] => 30
    )
)
и т.д.
```

Необходимо убрать дубли и перезаписать, чтоб имел такой вид:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => product_1
        [model] => model_1
        [option] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 47
                        [name] => Размер
                        [value] => 39
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 47
                        [name] => Размер
                        [value] => 40
                    )
            )
        [quantity] => 10
    ),
    [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => product_2
        [model] => model_2
        [option] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 55
                        [name] => Размер
                        [value] => 44
                    )
            )
        [quantity] => 30
    )
```

Модель трогать нельзя. Сейчас делаю так:

```
$keys=array(); // Массив ключей, которые уже встречались
  foreach($products as $k=>$val) {
   if(array_key_exists($val['model'],$keys)) {
    unset($products[$k]);
   } else {
    $keys[$val['model']]=1;
   }
  }
```

Сейчас убирает дубли, а как сделать чтоб еще дописывал из дублей `[option]` ?

Comment: а нельзя использовать промежуточный массив что ли? Итерировать ключи и удалять их в одном цикле чревато. Вы удаляете дубль, если в ключ уже был, в чем проблема взять сначала  оттуда `options` и добавить к конечному элементу?

Comment: зы: если модель трогать нельзя, то вы хотите эту логику в представление что ли записать?

Comment: @teran я тоже думал в этом направлении, давайте пробовать!
меня устроит любой вариант, который сделает вышеописанный  результат,
логику я напишу в контроллере, это не проблема.

Comment: Дак а в исходном массиве разные ведь "модели" бывают, то есть итоговый результат ведь состоит не из одного элемента? И почему `quantity` берется от первого результата?

Comment: @teran Да, бывают разные модели, и это надо учесть, Ключ quantity не важен.

Comment: Вопрос решен! Всем спасибо за помощь!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для конечного результата используйте новый массив. Хранить уже встретившиеся ключи смысла особо нет, надо "продукты" добавлять в результирующий массив с ключом - именем модели. Число товаров `quantity` имеет смысл, наверное, добавлять в массив `options`, т.к. в противном случае останется только значение из первого элемента, а вам скорее всего нужно знать сколько "обуви" и каких размеров в наличии.

В итоге алгоритм следующего вида. Если ключа имени-модели в результирующем массиве нет, то добавляем его, при этом `quantity` переносим в options. Если есть, то добавляем элемент в `options`, попутно перенося `quantity`.

```
$result = [];

//итерируем исходные данные
foreach($model as $m){
    //значение имение модели для сокращения
    $mname = $m['model'];

    // переносим quantity в option 
    $m['option'][0]['quantity'] = $m['quantity'] ;

    // Модель уже присутствует в результатах?
    if(isset($result[$mname])){
        // добавляем текущий option к результирующему массиву
        $result[$mname]['option'][] = $m['option'][0];
    }
    // модели в результатах нет.
    else {
        //убираем quantity, т.к. перенесли его в options
        unset($m['quantity']);
        // помещаем модель в результирующий массив
        $result[$mname] = $m; 
    }
}

//если нужны целочисленные ключи массива
$result = array_values($result);
```

В коде подразумеваем, что обрабатываем некоторый результат джойна таблиц продуктов их их "вариантов", и в `option` всегда находится ровно 1 элемент.

Результат выполнения имеет следующий вид:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => product_1
        [model] => model_1
        [option] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 47
                        [name] => Размер
                        [value] => 39
                        [quantity] => 10
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 47
                        [name] => Размер
                        [value] => 40
                        [quantity] => 20
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => product_2
        [model] => model_2
        [option] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [product_id] => 47
                        [name] => Размер
                        [value] => 40
                        [quantity] => 20
                    )

            )

    )
```

(в исходный массив был добавлен `product_2` для наглядности)

Comment: $teran Похоже на правду, если можно прокомментируйте пож каждую строчку кода.

Comment: @ultimatum дописал, попутно немного изменил код.

Comment: Огонь. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Вот рабочая версия:

```
$result = [];
foreach($products as $val){
$val['option'][0]['quantity'] = $val['quantity'];
 if(isset($result[$val['model']]))
 {
   $result[$val['model']]['option'][] = $val['option'][0];
 }
 else
 {
  $result[$val['model']] = $val;    
 }  
 unset($result[$val['model']]['quantity']);
}
```

Comment: Перезаписал(все ['option'] в одну кучу ), но надо немного подправить: у меня на странице разные модели в массиве `$val['model'] ` (модель_1, модель_2 и т.д.) , нужно чтоб переписал все ['option'] по $val['model'].

Comment: Можете запостить пример массива, что должно получится

Comment: Готово! Поправил вопрос.

Comment: я исправил,теперь работает с model